# Perl one liner using substitute with a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like this :

```
7th Aug 2020 10:18:35 am Bill Smith:
NW: RE: Matt Reid - EUC23284 - INC1020721599
7th Aug 2020 10:22:02 am Bill Smith:
VK: RE: don't think we send the price, pls help check what happened - INC1020721668
7th Aug 2020 11:00:06 am Bill Smith:
*mailbox handover*
7th Aug 2020 11:06:04 am Tom Jones:
BJ - RE: Megan Holleran Unmatched Trader Trades 08/06/2020 17:35 [Restricted - External] INC1020722335
7th Aug 2020 11:07:37 am Tom Jones:
DS - RE: All summit books missing from multiple reports in ICE INC1020722348
7th Aug 2020 12:36:10 pm Tom Jones:
NW - confirm trade receipt for Jon Lett from GFI ID: 1922979 INC1020723352
```

And I want it to look like this :

```
7th Aug 2020 10:18:35 am Bill Smith: NW: RE: Matt Reid - EUC23284 - INC1020721599
7th Aug 2020 10:22:02 am Bill Smith: VK: RE: don't think we send the price, pls help check what happened - INC1020721668
7th Aug 2020 11:00:06 am Bill Smith: *mailbox handover*
7th Aug 2020 11:06:04 am Tom Jones: BJ - RE: Megan Holleran Unmatched Trader Trades 08/06/2020 17:35 [Restricted - External] INC1020722335
7th Aug 2020 11:07:37 am Tom Jones: DS - RE: All summit books missing from multiple reports in ICE INC1020722348
7th Aug 2020 12:36:10 pm Tom Jones: NW - confirm trade receipt for Jon Lett from GFI ID: 1922979 INC1020723352
```

So I run this over the file, the goal is to take the new line off of the string ending with the persons name, followed by a colon. I want to change, in this case "Bill Smith:\n" and "Tom Jones:\n" to "Bill Smith: " and Tom Jones: ". If you look at the one liner, it does not work on the replace.

```
cat incfile | perl -p -e 's/\w+\s\w+\:\n/\w+\s\w+\:/g'

7th Aug 2020 10:18:35 am w+sw+:NW: RE: Matt Reid - EUC23284 - INC1020721599
7th Aug 2020 10:22:02 am w+sw+:VK: RE: don't think we send the price, pls help check what happened - INC1020721668
7th Aug 2020 11:00:06 am w+sw+:*mailbox handover*
7th Aug 2020 11:06:04 am w+sw+:BJ - RE: Megan Holleran Unmatched Trader Trades 08/06/2020 17:35 [Restricted - External] INC1020722335
7th Aug 2020 11:07:37 am w+sw+:DS - RE: All summit books missing from multiple reports in ICE INC1020722348
7th Aug 2020 12:36:10 pm w+sw+:NW - confirm trade receipt for Jon Lett from GFI ID: 1922979 INC1020723352
```

Answer (score 4):

You were going for

```sh
perl -pe's/(\w+\s\w+:)\n/$1 /'
```

The substring matched by the first capture (`()`) is assigned to `$1`, which you can use in the replacement expression.

---

The above can be simplified/optimized to

```sh
perl -pe's/\w+\s\w+:\K\n/ /'
```

What matched before `\K` is "kept" (not replaced), so only the line feed is replaced (with a space).

---

Alternatively, you could simply replace the line feeds of odd-numbered lines.

```sh
perl -pe's/\n/ / if $. % 2'
```

Comment: How could i add a space after the colon ? or in this case after the $1

Comment: Woops. Fixed! Think of the replacement expression as a string literal.  In fact, `s/.../.../` is the same thing as `s/.../ "..." /e`. So you can use `s/.../ $1 . " " /e`, `s/.../ "$1 " /e` or just `s/.../$1 /`.

Comment: Regexp special escape `\K` appeared with perl 5.10.0, just in case someone is wondering.

Comment: @Ouki, Yes, but that version came out 13 years ago. If someone is using an 18 year old version of Perl, I would expect them to mention it.